# PHP group values from array

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have this array:

```
Array ( 
    [061716v] => 1 
    [061610A] => 1 
    [062433AP] => 1 
    [063868M] => 2 
    [059173V] => 3 
    [061579A] => 3 
    [062404AP] => 3 
    [059179V] => 4 
    [061582A] => 4 
    [061697V] => 4 
    [062407AP] => 4 
)
```

How can i get this:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => 061716v,061610A,062433AP 
    [2] => 063868M 
    [3] => 059173V,061579A,062404AP 
    [4] => 059179V,061582A,061697V,062407AP 
)
```

Comment: _How can i get this?_ By coding. I think

Comment: What Saad means is: you need to show the code you coded yourself to solve this. Then we can help with that code. We are not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP single `foreach()` will do the job:-

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($initial_array as $key=>$val){

    $final_array[$val] = isset($final_array[$val]) ? $final_array[$val].','.$key : $key;

}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/lSKE2

Comment: Thank you Alive to Die, you save the day! thanks you

Answer (score 1):

```
// You also can use implode to skip isset checks
$group = [];

foreach ($initialArray as $key => $value) {
    $group[$value][] = $key;
}

$result = array_map(function($v) { return implode(",",$v); }, $group);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: `foreach()` and `array_map()` at the same time will increase the burden.Check the performance difference of your code and mine:- https://3v4l.org/0FLUN/perf#output  And https://3v4l.org/lSKE2/perf#output  . And the difference is for such smaller array. think what happen if array become bigger

Comment: BTW i am not telling that your code is wrong. Just a very lengthy way to do easier thing